# Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Test.Framework.TestSuite’ when trying to create unit tests

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hft

I'm writing a small library in Haskell, and want to have tests to accompany it. For testing I intend to use HFT, and the project as a whole is managed by stack. `stack test` fails for some reason with the following output:

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( test/Ini.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/ini-tests/ini-tests-tmp/Main.o )                                                                      │····························
[2 of 2] Compiling Paths_schemer    ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/ini-tests/autogen/Paths_schemer.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/ini-tests/ini-tests-tm│····························
p/Paths_schemer.o )                                                                                                                                                                                               │····························
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  │····························
/stuff/projects/schemer/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/ini-tests/autogen/Paths_schemer.hs:54:39: error:                                                                                 │····························
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Test.Framework.TestSuite’                                                                                                                                            │····························
    No module named ‘Test.Framework’ is imported.                                                                                                                                                                 │····························
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  │····························
/stuff/projects/schemer/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/ini-tests/autogen/Paths_schemer.hs:55:38: error:                                                                                 │····························
    Not in scope: ‘Test.Framework.makeTestSuite’                                                                                                                                                                  │····························
    No module named ‘Test.Framework’ is imported.                                                                                                                                                                 │····························
```

My Ini.hs file that will later contain the tests is very bare-bone, just

```
import Test.Framework

main :: IO ()
main = htfMain htf_thisModulesTests
```

My `package.yaml` is

```
name:                schemer
version:             0.1.0.0
github:              "mpevnev/schemer"
license:             BSD3
author:              "Michail Pevnev"
maintainer:          "mpevnev@gmail.com"
copyright:           ""

extra-source-files: []

# Metadata used when publishing your package
# synopsis:            Short description of your package
# category:            Web

# To avoid duplicated efforts in documentation and dealing with the
# complications of embedding Haddock markup inside cabal files, it is
# common to point users to the README.md file.
description:         Please see the README on GitHub at <https://github.com/mpevnev/schemer#readme>

dependencies:
- attoparsec
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- text


library:
  source-dirs: src

tests:
  ini-tests:
    main:                Ini.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    - -F
    - -pgmF htfpp
    dependencies:
    - schemer
    - text
    - HTF
```

Here's the autogenerated `schemer.cabal`:

```
-- This file has been generated from package.yaml by hpack version 0.28.2.
--
-- see: https://github.com/sol/hpack
--
-- hash: 17ae623236b8f5b101f56373c975656e898efa7506acb143db7375f229509a79

name:           schemer
version:        0.1.0.0
description:    Please see the README on GitHub at <https://github.com/mpevnev/schemer#readme>
homepage:       https://github.com/mpevnev/schemer#readme
bug-reports:    https://github.com/mpevnev/schemer/issues
author:         Michail Pevnev
maintainer:     mpevnev@gmail.com
license:        BSD3
license-file:   LICENSE
build-type:     Simple
cabal-version:  >= 1.10

source-repository head
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/mpevnev/schemer

library
  exposed-modules:
      Control.Scheme.Ini
      Control.Schemer
  other-modules:
      Paths_schemer
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      attoparsec
    , base >=4.7 && <5
    , text
  default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite ini-tests
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Ini.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_schemer
  hs-source-dirs:
      test
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -F -pgmF htfpp
  build-depends:
      HTF
    , attoparsec
    , base >=4.7 && <5
    , schemer
    , text
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

I'm not sure what's wrong and what is this Paths_schemer thing. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `.cabal` file? You may need to add the package to `build-depends` there.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Added the contents of the cabal file.

Comment: What if you remove the two occurences of `other-modules: Path_schemer`?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia It compiles. Odd. One would expect generated by stack stuff to be valid. Maybe you have an idea how to instruct stack to not generate this?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Tried setting `other-modules` setting in the `package.yaml` to an empty list, worked like a charm. Not sure what was going on with that, maybe some weird default? If you write up an answer from this, I'll accept. It was yours intuition, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options `-F -pgmF htfpp` are switched on globally. This applies the HTF preprocessor to all the files of the test suite, including the autogenerated `Paths_schemer`.

The more scalable solution is to enable the preprocessor only on files that import `Test.Framework`, using the `OPTIONS_GHC` pragma in each one:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF htfpp #-}
```

Another way is to set `other-modules: []` in the test-suite section in `package.yaml` to avoid generating `Paths_schemer`, although that only solves the problem for this one module.